# How to associate multiple SSL certificates with one server (C language)?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

Is it possible to let one server have multiple certificates?
To authenticate, the server sends all certificates to the client, and the client verifies according to pre-installed CA's. Does it workable under current OpenSSL API?

Specifically, for function "SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file()" what happens if call it twice with different certificates?

Answer (score 0):

`Is it possible to let one server have multiple certificates?`

It is possible that a server have multiple certificates as it can have multiple private keys.

`To authenticate, the server sends all certificates to the client, and the client verifies according to pre-installed CA's. Does it workable under current OpenSSL API?`

As per my knowledge of SSL protocol, server sends only one certificate, not multiple and too only of its choice.

As per my knowledge of OpenSSL and after seeing the code of `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file`, if you call it twice, it will override previously set certificate. As you intended that it will use second certificate, it will not happen.

Comment: If a server is allowed to have multiple certificates, then how can the server use them? Can you supply more detail?

Comment: By this, I mean a server can possess multiple certificates. How to use them is the part of implementation. As per my current knowledge after reading SSL RFC, I am not able to find how to achieve what you want. A server can have multiple certificate of different types of public key say DH, EC, RSA and in this case, server can select on the basis of client handshake message about what public keys are supported?

Comment: But the file can have multiple certificates one below the other.